# angular merged into window object by webpack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have a very strange problem with webpack.

I have this webpack.config file:

https://github.com/saike/maluvich-browser/blob/master/webpack.config.babel.js

And i import angular through es6 module imports:

https://github.com/saike/maluvich-browser/blob/master/src/maluvich.js

Then i bootstrap angular app as usual after DOMContentLoaded event:

https://github.com/saike/maluvich-browser/blob/master/index.html

But...

When i try to console.log(window), it shows this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Looks like webpack or something merged angular and window together. I can't find the problem.

I will be very happy if someone help me. Thank you!

Comment: It's actually what you would expect for, if angular isn't mount to the global window object, how can you access it in your app, think about what jQuery/$ does.

Comment: no, this is not i expect for. Because angular mounted to window too: [screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/HSzZn0H1mNnXwUfACv18S5WeYNmFj9.png), but it's also merged to window. Window has angular's properties and methods, like: `fromJson(), copy(), extend()`

Comment: i never seen situation like this before.

Answer (score 0):

OK. After many hours of pain, i found that it's happened because of common chunk plugin.

```
 new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('maluvich-vendor', 'maluvich-vendor.js', Infinity)
```

After removing this line, window object start work as usual.